# Regex 'blacklist' character validator returning odd result

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Here's the Regex:

```
^[^~^\\/&$-+]*$
```

Here's the test string:

```
a(b
```

Even though `(` doesn't appear in the blacklist, this returns NO matches. That makes NO sense.  Anyone know why?

Comment: put the hyphen at the end, because it defines a range of characters between `$` and `+` (see the ascii table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the dash at the end of the character class:

Change from:

```
^[^~^\/&$-+]*$
         ^---- Here the dash works as a range instead of a single character
```

To

```
^[^~^\/&$+-]*$
          ^--- Here works as the single "-" character
```

Btw, as [Mr. Lama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477563/mr-llama) pointed in his comment you can also escape the dash like this:

```
^[^~^\/&$\-+]*$
         ^-- escaped here
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's standard or not, but many implementations will allow you to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: @Mr.Llama yes, that would work too. I'll add it to the answer.